# syntax error near unexpected token error in shell script

Tags: bash

i have the following shell script-

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter the full path of script";
read path;
while true
    ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -q $path || ( nohup php -f $path & )
done
```

I am executing in following way -

```
bash test.sh
enter the full path of script
php_test.php
test.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
test.sh: line 7: `done'
```

there is a php_test.php in the same directory as the present one. PLease help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is not related to php.

Comment: Also escape `$path` with double quotes to prevent spaces in the variable to have bash consider it as two arguments after expansion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `help while`:

> ```
> while: while COMMANDS; do COMMANDS; done
> ```

You're missing the `do`.

```
while true
do
 ...
done
```